# How do I update my model with an each do loop and delayed_job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, delayed-job

I'm gathering data with the Facebook API and get_object requests with [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) are slow, so I'm trying to use [delayed_job_active_record](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). However, I am having difficulty updating my model with the each do loop. @facebook is an array of IDs, and it works when I don't use the .delay method, but doesn't save when I use it.

How do I get this to work? I'm not sure where to put the .delay, or if I have to write it differently. Thanks for your help!

```
 @facebook.each do |f|
 Like.find_by_f_id(f).delay.name = @graph.get_object(f)["name"]
 Like.find_by_f_id(f).delay.category = @graph.get_object(f)["category"]
 Like.find_by_f_id(f).delay.save
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 @facebook.each do |f|
   Like.find_by_f_id(f).delay.update_attributes(
     :name => @graph.get_object(f)["name"],
     :category => @graph.get_object(f)["category"])
 end
```

Comment: it worked! but the page continues to load until the background process is done, currently its in my authentications#create action. any suggestions?